# SharePoint 2013 upgrade give error?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

After running SharePoint products configuration wizard it give error at step 9:

```
04/04/2015 14:52:09.36  psconfigui (0x933C) 0x8B14  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxmn   WARNING Exception occured when querying old feature with id [f7937973-0cf9-4f2d-a549-be2d3c25b772], skipping. Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Failed to find the XML file at location '15\Template\Features\NintexWorkflowAdmin\feature.xml' 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPXmlDocCache.GetGlobalXmlDocument(String pathTemplateRelativeXml, SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Int32 compatibilityLevel) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarmFeatureDefinitionContext.LoadFileAsXmlDocument(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, String featureRelativePath) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_Scope() 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.PopulateFeaturesTable(StringBuilder sqlstr)    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Comment: What u doing, applying "cu"? Error is telling me u have nintex work flow installed which causing the issue.make sure it is properly configured

Comment: You are going to need to add a bit more detail.  Upgrading from what?  How was it performed?  Please check your upgrade log file and search for "Error" as well and post those results.

Answer (score 0):

Before You Can update to a newer version, you must ensure that your third party tools are already update and correctly installed and also configured. Otherwise you receive an error like this. In your case that is nintex that causes the problem.